# $[f(z)]^{-1}$ for $z\neq 0$ and $h(a)=0$ is analytic

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm reading [Conway's complex analysis book](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=9LtfZr1snG0C&printsec=frontcover&hl=pt-BR&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false) and on page 105 the author made the following commentary:

> Suppose that $f$ has a pole at $z=a$; it follows that $[f(z)]^{-1}$ has
>   a removable singularity at $z=a$. Hence, $h(z)=[f(z)]^{-1}$ for $z\neq
>  a$ and $h(a)=0$ is analytic in $B(a;R)$ for some $R\gt 0$.

I didn't understand why the function $h(z)$ he defined is analytic at $a$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $f$ has a pole at $z=a$, then $\lim_{z\to a}|f(z)|=\infty$, so in particular $f(z)\ne0$ for all $z$ in a neighborhood of $a$, and so $h$ has a singularity at $z=a$ (Definition 1.1). Therefore, by Theorem 1.2 $h$ has a removable singularity at $z=a$ iff $\lim_{z\to a}(z-a)h(z)=0$. But this is trivially true, because both $z-a\to0$ and $h(z)\to0$ as $z\to a$.

Comment: a removable singularity is an isolated "singularity" such that when setting $f(a) = C$ then $f(z)$ becomes holomorphic/analytic around $a$. that if $a$ is an isolated "singularity" and $f(z) (z-a) \to 0$ then  the singularity is removable is [Riemann's theorem on isolated singularities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removable_singularity#Riemann.27s_theorem), which requires its own proof.

Comment: I do understand that $[f(z)]^{-1}$ has a removable singularity at $a$. What I didn't understand is why $h(z)=[f(z)]^{-1}$ for $z\neq
 0$ and $h(a)=0$ is analytic. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Since $[f(z)]^{-1}$ has a removable singularity at $z=a$ (see the other answer of this post), there exists an analytical function h such that $h(z)=[f(z)]^{-1}$ for $z\neq a$. But what is $h(a)$? Since $h$ is continuous, the only possible choice to $h(a)$ is to be $0$, because $\lim_{z\to a}h(z)=\lim_{z\to a}[f(z)]^{-1}=0$.